# Legend in biograph plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a `biograph` object, and I want to "color-code" the edges and vertices.

Is it possible to get legends in the biograph plot, similar to the ones in `plot`.

My code is like this:

```
Sys = sparse(from_nodes, to_nodes,1,s,s);
SysTri = tril(Sys + Sys');

h = view(biograph(SysTri,[],'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','off')); 

%% One of the parts I'm coloring:
set(h.Nodes(node_list1),'Color',[1 0.4 0.4])
fowEdges = getedgesbynodeid(h,get(h.Nodes(node_list1),'ID'));
revEdges = getedgesbynodeid(h,get(h.Nodes(fliplr(node_list1)),'ID'));
edges = [fowEdges;revEdges];
set(edges,'LineColor',[1 0 0])
set(edges,'LineWidth',1.5)
```

Now, I would like to do something like this:

```
legend(h,'Node list 1', 'Node list 2');
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is something you only want to do a few times, you could probably do it manually.

You can try to print to figure from the biograph window, and add labels there.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
legend(h.Nodes(node_list1), {'Node list 1'}, 'Location','SouthWest', 'Color','g');
```

Comment: Thanks George. 

I get an error when I use the code above: `Error using legend (line 200)
Handle must be an axes or child of an axes.` It seems like none of the normal plot function works for biographs. I tried doing it using annotations, but the annotation objects just appeared in a new (empty) figure.

Comment: @Robert P.: Maybe try : legend(edges,{'Node list 1'},....). I am sorry this is all I know. :)